# Parse XML and generate UI in UIWebView iPad App

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I will receive an XML from Server, and have to parse the xml file, and based on that have to populate textbox, listbox etc(a form) in UIWebView.

I know XML parsing for iOS using NSXML, I do not know how to fire events to generate Form/UI at runtime.

Any tutorials or idea pls.

Comment: Why don't you generate the html you need server side and just inject in your webview?

Comment: Passing html back and forth increases the load if you see large picture. Passing xml and returning data in xlm makes it faster, more managable. And then, changing server side is something not in my hands. Wat I will have to do is, parse xml and generate HTML code  keep appending in a string and at the end feed it to WebView. Is there any tutorial where I can learn this thing quickly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created your HTML as a NSString already, you can load it into the UIWebView by using the method [`loadHTMLString:baseURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a). For example:

```
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] init];
//Download XML, parse it and turn it into HTML.
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
//if you have to do any thing else to the HTML string do it here
[htmlString release];
```

Changing the htmlString after calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` won't update the UIWebView. You will need to call the method again, sending the modified string.

If you need further help, comment below and I'll edit my answer or comment back.

Comment: Any tutorial which can get me going ?

Comment: On parsing the XML to HTML? can you give an example of the XML your downloading?

Comment: Sure. This is how it looks like: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FormConfig>
 <Form>Contact</Form>
 <property>
  <row>
   <type>textbox</type>
   <label>FName</label><value></value>
  </row>
  <row>
   <property>Checkbox</property>
   <label>Contact Preference</label>        <values>Email,Phone</values>
  </row>
  
 </property>
</FormConfig>' Or if I can generate Views from parsing this xml will work fine too.

Comment: I'd recommend using TBXML, it's the fastest, and it works best with small->medium XML files, There are guides here http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Loading_an_XML_document.html (and you download it from the same site)

Comment: Its easier to go with TableView based forms than the approach of HTML forms.

Comment: @Kunal, well you'll still need to pass the XML, into an NSArray.

Comment: I am trying this way- parse the XMl and add data with fields to NSArray, and populate the cells the way you want from NSArray.